# Twilio library doesn't work in Rails, but works outside rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

First time poster here ( be gentle, I've done my research! )

I'm new to the Ruby ecosystem having come from another language, but this strikes me as odd. I've added the twilio-ruby library to my Gemfile, done bundle install / tried bundle update

bundle show twilio-ruby
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/twilio-ruby-3.11.5

However, I get the following error when trying *any* of the examples.

`Undefined method 'messages' for #<Twilio::REST::Client::Account:0x00000102cea740>`

Substitute for Calls, etc etc. Nothing works. Not even @client.account.sms.messages ( the legacy calls ).

I'm familiar with pry and have done @client.pry yielding self.account.methods.sort and these methods / class members are not present in the module at all.

So what does work? ruby test.rb containing:

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new '{{removed}}', '{{removed}}'
#@client.pry


p @client.account.messages.create(
  :from => '+1XXX',
  :to => '+1XXX',
  :body => 'Hey there!'
)
```

If I put the same code at the top of my application.rb, outside the application class delcaration it works.

Where else have I tried? Controllers, Models, stand alone classes imported and called in controllers/models. It seems after Rails is bootstrapped it doesn't work. I'm so confused.

I'm pretty good at debugging, so any tips in that direction would be appreciated!

Versions: Ruby 2.1.2, Rails 4.0.4, twilio-ruby 3.11.5

After each and every change I make I do restart the rails server.

#### UPDATE

```
config/application.rb

require 'twilio-ruby'
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new '{{removed}}', '{{removed}}'
#@client.pry


p @client.account.messages.create(
  :from => '+',
  :to => '+',
  :body => 'Hey there!'
)

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

#require 'twilio-ruby'
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new '{{removed}}', '{{removed}}'
#@client.pry


p @client.account.messages.create(
  :from => '+',
  :to => '+',
  :body => 'Hey there!'
)
```

the call to twilio-ruby prior to the call to bundler works.

the call to twilio-ruby after the call to bundler does not work.

Comment: That's definitely odd (and not replicable for me). Does this still happen if you start an empty Rails project, adding only the `twilio-ruby` gem?

Comment: Does it work if you uncomment the `require 'twilio-ruby'` _after_ the `Bundler.requre` call?

Comment: Try with @client.account.sms.messages.create

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I've written two detailed blog posts on integration Twilio into a Rails 4.x app: [Part 1](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html) and [Part 2](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/10/twilio-on-rails-part-2-rails-4-app-sending-sms-mms.html).

Answer (score 0):

6 years later and I'm sharing the culprit for this issue: spring

I ran `spring stop` and suddenly everything loaded as expected.